# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkfifo'

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am trying to do Coreference resolution using python. I have downloaded Stanford python wrapper from github and also installed all the required dependencies.

But I get an error at line 170, in start_server:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkfifo'
```

Comment: can you show us your code with line 170 included ?

Comment: Are you running on Windows? `mkfifo()` is not available there.

Comment: yes i am running windows..then what is the alternative?

Comment: @mazza i have juz downloaded the stanford core nlp python wrapper from python..the error is seen in sock wrap.py file

Comment: @Deepanjali, a Linux VM?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no not a linux vm...windows 64 bit machine..

Comment: @Deepanjali, no, I meant the alternative would be a Linux VM :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Do os module in python have a mkfifo()

Comment: @Deepanjali, not on Windows, no.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - See the duplicate

Comment: mkfifo() exist in python of cygwin